# Java: Syntax error on token "-", Expression expected after this token

Tags: java

Well hello guys, i'm starting the programmer life now, i'm really new into it, but i'm trying really, really hard and i'm making some easy programs to run on eclipse console, it's very simples 'cause i'm just getting started... well, everything went out ok, except for this one program, i can't make it work in no way... i'm gonna put it all here so if there's anything really, really wrong tell me, and i'm also going to expecific the problem that eclipse found... Here it is:

```
public class Pagamento {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int vvalor;
            int vpagto;
            int vtroco;
            String voperador;

            vvalor = 200;
            vpagto = 250;
            voperador = -;

            if (vpagto > vvalor){
                System.out.println ("Troco:" + vpagto - vvalor);
            }if (vpagto = vvalor ){
                System.out.println ("Troco:" + 0);  
            }if (vpagto < vvalor){
                System.out.println ("Transação inconcluída!");
            }

    }

}
```

I had to define the " - " 'cause it asked to (when i did it, it said in the first System.out.println, that 'the operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int and in the line' "}if (vpagto = vvalor ){" it appeared the error "can't convert from int to boolean), and when i did defined, it just gave this error on the line "voperador = -;":
Syntax error on token "-", Expression expected after this token. What does that mean ? Is everything so wrong ? What should i do to fix it ? Please help me, i try to search but i found nothing like this here, nothing that could solve my problem... thanks and please help !

Comment: I highly suggest reading the official [language basics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html). It is concise and well-written and will fill you in on these details. The mistakes you are making here are very fundamental. By the way, make sure you pay attention to the actual line the compiler tells you the problem is in when it finds an error. Your "operator - is undefined" error has nothing to do with the `voperador = -;` line.

Comment: Right man, gonna train my english harder so i can understand it all easily ! I can understand somethings but other things i just run to Google Tradutor and it's always a bad idea haha, thx for all the support !

Comment: It must be horrible to read a Java tutorial through Google translate :S .  By the way, check out http://pt.stackoverflow.com/, it is a new Portuguese version of StackOverflow.

Comment: Ooh yeah man, thx ! Gonna use both, the english is always more helpful, btw it' a universal language right haha thx dude, in some minutes you passed some good experience to me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace     `}if (vpagto = vvalor ){`
 with     `}if (vpagto ==vvalor ){`

Also keep `-` with in ""(double qoutes)  like    `voperador ="-";`

Comment: Well, thank you so much ! I removed the String voperator, and did this, and it worked cause that line had no error now, still in the line "System.out.println ("Troco:" + vpagto - vvalor);" i had the error " 'the operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int ", and if i add the string voperator, it just happen the same error as before...

Comment: @user3483578 try with        `System.out.println ("Troco:" + (vpagto - vvalor));`

Comment: Dude, you're my hero ! it worked out great ! Haha, thanks! That was boring me to death ! I spend all day into this, you're right, i'd seem it on internet right last week, how couldn't i remember ? You're awesome man, thx !

Comment: @user3483578 The time it takes to read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html is less than the "all day" you spent banging your head on your keyboard. You should accept this answer if you found it to be the most helpful. You can do this by clicking the big check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thx man, it's done, gonna read it for shure, study it's never too much, guess i get too enthusiastic and skip some parts haha, guess it happens to everyone... thanks again man !

Answer (score 4):

it should be `voperador = "-";` You have missed the double quotes. Strings are required to be enclosed within double qoutes

Comment: Well, here's the weird part, if i put it in double quotes, the error 'the operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int' continues, if i remove, the error "Syntax error on token "-", Expression expected after this token", i don't get it...

Comment: You need to change System.out.println ("Troco:" + vpagto - vvalor);  to System.out.println ("Troco:" + (vpagto - vvalor)); and if (vpagto = vvalor ) to if (vpagto == vvalor )

Answer (score 0):

voperador is a String, which can't be assigned to -. If you want the string to be "-", then use voperador = "-";

Comment: Well, here's the weird part, if i put it in double quotes, the error 'the operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int' continues, if i remove, the error "Syntax error on token "-", Expression expected after this token", i don't get it...

Answer (score 0):

For your first error: This line isn't valid:

```
voperador = -;
```

String constants must go in quotes:

```
voperador = "-";
```

A `-` by itself is either a unary negation operator (e.g. `-a`) or a binary subtraction operator (e.g. `a - b`). The error you are seeing is the result of the compiler becoming very confused as to why a negation/subtraction operator was just hanging out between an equal sign and a semicolon.

---

For your second error: You have this:

```
if (vpagto = vvalor )
```

But you should have this:

```
if (vpagto == vvalor )
```

In Java, a single `=` means "assignment". Comparisons are done with the double `==`. The reason you saw the error you saw is because Java evaluates the expression `a = b` to the value of `a` after the assignment (that's the rule), which in this case happens to be of type `int` (since `vpagto` is an `int`). At the same time, it expects the condition in an `if` statement to be a `boolean` (e.g. `if (true) ...`). The compiler was confused because it wanted a `boolean` but you gave it an `int`.

---

For your third error, you have this:

```
("Troco:" + vpagto - vvalor)
```

But what you really mean is this:

```
("Troco:" + (vpagto - vvalor))
```

Java evaluates expressions from left to right. As a convenience, it lets you add pretty much anything you want to a string, and the result is a string version of the values you've specified. However, this only works with `+`, there's no special definition of `-` for strings. Since it goes left to right, first `"Troco:" + vpagto` is evaluated, and that is a string. But then you try to subtract `vvalor` from a string, and the compiler complains. By adding parentheses, you tell it to perform the math on the integers first, before attempting to append the result to a string.

---

The errors you are making here are very basic. You should really go through the official [Language Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html) tutorial.

Comment: Well, here's the weird part, if i put it in double quotes, the error 'the operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int' continues, if i remove, the error "Syntax error on token "-", Expression expected after this token", i don't get it...

Comment: @user3483578 Yeah, but that "operator - is undefined" error is on a different line. Be sure to pay attention to what line the compiler indicates when it complains. You solve one error and the compiler ends up running into the next one. You have to solve *all* of them. See my edit.